# Display different random number on every jButton click

Tags: java, swing

I'm building my first Java app and can't seem to make it work. It's a slot machine with GUI and separate class that works well on it's own.

This is the addSlots method:

```
    lblSlot1 = new JLabel("?");
    lblSlot1.setBounds(10, 50, 100, 20);
    panel.add(lblSlot1);

    lblSlot2 = new JLabel("?");
    lblSlot2.setBounds(110, 50, 100, 20);
    panel.add(lblSlot2);

    lblSlot3 = new JLabel("?");
    lblSlot3.setBounds(210, 50, 100, 20);
    panel.add(lblSlot3);

    lblResult = new JLabel("Result goes here");
    lblResult.setBounds(10, 100, 100, 20);
    panel.add(lblResult);
} 
public void addButtons(){ 
    btnSpin = new JButton("Spin");
    btnSpin.setBounds(50, 200, 100, 20);
    btnSpin.addActionListener(new SpinHandler());
    panel.add(btnSpin);

    btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
    btnExit.setBounds(250, 200, 100, 20);
    btnExit.addActionListener(new ExitHandler());
    panel.add(btnExit);
```

The action listener:

```
class SpinHandler implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("Spin");

        SlotMachine sm = new SlotMachine();

        lblSlot1.setText(String.valueOf(sm.getSlot1()));
        lblSlot2.setText(String.valueOf(sm.getSlot2()));
        lblSlot3.setText(String.valueOf(sm.getSlot3()));

        lblResult.setText(String.valueOf(sm.getResult()));

    }
```

It only generates 0, 0, 0 as opposed to random numbers.

This is the slotmachine class:

```
public int getSlot1(){
    return slot1;
}
public int getSlot2(){
    return slot2;
}
public int getSlot3(){
    return slot3;
}

public void spin(){

    Random rand = new Random();
    slot1 = rand.nextInt(10);
    slot2 = rand.nextInt(10);
    slot3 = rand.nextInt(10);
```

Comment: You forget to call `spin` method in `actionPerformed` .

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you forgot to call the **spin**() method inside your **getSlot**#() methods

Comment: Just had to add sm.spin(); to the action handler, thanks!